# CAS Authentication failing when user navigating from one web app to another web app

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

We have two web applications. Both are enabled with CAS authentication. We can navigate from web application(Application A) to another one(Application B). Some times sessionManagementFilter  is redirecting to session expired page ,when user navigating from Application A to B.We are getting session invalid page for Application B. Here is our spring configuration settings in applicationContext-security.xml file.

Any idea what is the causing the issue. Prompt response is appreciable.

```
<http entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" >
        <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casProcessingFilter" />
    <custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter"   before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />

    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout.xhtml" logout-success-url="calltoolSecurity{CAS_URL}/logout" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="sessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    <!-- this permits redirection to session timeout page from javascript/ajax or http -->
    <beans:property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="actInvalidSessionStrategy" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="actInvalidSessionStrategy" class="com.avivausa.api.web.JsfRedirectStrategy">
         <beans:constructor-arg name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/pages/system/errorSessionExpired.xhtml" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that both application using the same CAS server to login.

Comment: Both aplications are using same CAS server, but spring security versions are different.CAS application and Application A is using spring security 2.0 version and Application B is using spring security 3.0 version